# How to find and plot integral of data set

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have an acceleration data set that I'm trying to convert to displacement in an excel file. It's arranged in two columns of time and acceleration. How do I integrate this (as it is not a function) then plot the result?

Comment: Interpolate and integrate. Or simply sum up the elements. Or or or.. this is unfortunately not very specific to Mathematica. It is a math question and once you have cleared what you want to do, it can be *implemented* in Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Take your `data={{ti,ai},...}` to form an interpolation function

```
acc=Interpolation[data, ....]
```

and integrate twice or use DSolve

```
DSolve[{x''[t] == Interpolation[data][t] }, x, t]
```

Initial conditions have to be adapted

Comment: Please don't post 2 answers with ..

Comment: Hehe.. I guess you already knew :) You can simply *edit* your own answer. No need for a new one.